# How to use function add associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

So I need a function to be able to add elements to a associative array, along with a counter to count the number of this function called.
Here is what I got so far:

```
<?php
    //1
    $Globals = [];
    $counter = 0;
    function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName){
    $course[courseCode] = $courseName;
    return $course();
    $counter ++;
}
    $Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS370', 'Introduction to Web Development');
    $Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS475', 'Advance Web Development');
    $Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS560', 'Introduction to Syber Security');
    $Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS564', 'Hacking Technic');
    //2
    echo 'You have a total of $counter courses now!';
?>
```

Obviously it is wrong, can someone let me know where and how to do this properly?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to write a function for this?  Why not just do `Globals[$courseCode] = $courseName` instead of calling your functions.  Then just do `echo 'You have a total of ' . count($Globals) . ' courses now!';`

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with `return $course()`, I imagine, you should drop off the `()` since I don't think that's a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code.

- You return a function with an array ? I don't see what you're trying to do here, simply return the array.

`return $course();`

to

`return $course;`

- You return before you actually increment the counter variable, so it's never getting incremented !

So :

```
$course[courseCode] = $courseName;
return $course;
$counter ++;
```

to

```
$course[courseCode] = $courseName;
$counter++;
return $course;
```

- You're not passing that counter variable anywhere. To do what you want, you need to pass it to the function by reference.

So :

```
function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName)
{
    $course[$courseCode] = $courseName;
    $counter++;
    return $course;
}
```

to

```
function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName, &$counter)
{
    $course[$courseCode] = $courseName;
    $counter++;
    return $course;
}
```

Here's the final code fixed :

```
<?php
//1
$Globals = [];
$counter = 0;
function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName, &$counter)
{
    $course[$courseCode] = $courseName;
    $counter++;
    return $course;
}

$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS370', 'Introduction to Web Development', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS475', 'Advance Web Development', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS560', 'Introduction to Syber Security', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS564', 'Hacking Technic', $counter);
//2
echo 'You have a total of $counter courses now!';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer with explanations in the code

```
<?php

    $Globals = [];
    $counter = 0;

    /**
     * @param  array $course
     * @param  string $courseCode
     * @param  string $courseName
     * @param  int $counter
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName, $counter){
        $course[$courseCode] = $courseName;

        // inside a function, you cannot use a global variable, you have to get it as argument and return it
        $counter++;

        // do the return at the end of the function because nothing else is performed after this
        return array(
            $course,
            $counter
        );
    }

    list($Globals, $counter) = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS370', 'Introduction to Web Development', $counter);
    list($Globals, $counter) = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS475', 'Advance Web Development', $counter);
    list($Globals, $counter) = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS560', 'Introduction to Syber Security', $counter);
    list($Globals, $counter) = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS564', 'Hacking Technic', $counter);

    // use double quotes "" if you want $counter to be echoed as the value of the variable $counter, not the word '$counter'
    echo "You have a total of $counter courses now!";
    // it is good practice to add a line break, this improves the script output
    echo PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: It's good practice to use `{}` around variables when echo'ing them out.  In this case it works fine, but still fwiw.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your code is working as well.

Answer (score -1):

This is very strange way of doing this.  If you absolutely have to do it in the way your code alludes, this will work:

```
$Globals = [];
$counter = 0;

function array_push_assoc($course, $courseCode, $courseName, &$count){
    $course[$courseCode] = $courseName;
    $count++;
    return $course;
}

$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS370', 'Introduction to Web Development', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS475', 'Advance Web Development', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS560', 'Introduction to Syber Security', $counter);
$Globals = array_push_assoc($Globals, 'CIS564', 'Hacking Technic', $counter);

echo "You have a total of {$counter} courses now!";
```

That said, a much cleaner (imo) way of doing this would be:

```
$Globals = [];
$Globals['CIS370'] = 'Introduction to Web Development';
$Globals['CIS475'] = 'Advance Web Development';
$Globals['CIS560'] = 'Introduction to Syber Security';
$Globals['CIS564'] = 'Hacking Technic';

echo 'You have a total of '. count($Globals) .' courses now!';
```

Comment: I was writing the same *cleaner* solution out as you posted this.  I agree, I don't see the purpose of the function or adding the count to the array when you can use the count() function.

Comment: I upvoted it, someone else downvoted.  If you were directing that at me...

Comment: Not directed at you.  Was just wondering if whoever did was still around

Comment: I agree, but the requirement require me to use function to acomplish that. And this is the only way I can think of...